# Part of the string is missing when trying to replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

```
[TITLE|prefix=X|suffix=a] [STORENAME|prefix=b] [DYNAMIC|limit=10|seperator=-|random=1|reverse=1|prefix=c]
```

I would like to replace the values of all `prefix` attributes with `hello`. So the goal is that the string looks like this:

```
[TITLE|prefix=hello|suffix=a] [STORENAME|prefix=hello] [DYNAMIC|limit=10|seperator=-|random=1|reverse=1|prefix=hello]
```

This is what I have tried:

```js
const obj = {};
obj.prefix = "[TITLE|prefix=a|suffix=x] [STORENAME|prefix=b] [DYNAMIC|limit=10|seperator=-|random=1|reverse=1|prefix=c]";

function replace(search, replace) {
  const regex = new RegExp(`(?<=\\[${search}\\|[^\\]]*${replace}=)[^|\\]]+`); 
  obj.prefix = obj.prefix.replace(regex, 'hello');
}

replace('TITLE', 'prefix');
replace('STORENAME', 'prefix');
replace('DYNAMIC', 'prefix');
console.log(obj.prefix);
```

As you see it works fine!

I have used almost the same code for my project but it fails. You can check my project on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzuq3cw1/). Just type anything on an input field and check the console. You will see that the value of first `prefix` will be changed but 2 further `prefix` attributes are missing.

So this is what I get:

```
[TITLE|prefix=anything|suffix=a] [STORENAME] [DYNAMIC|limit=10|seperator=-|random=1|reverse=1]
```

And this is what I should get:

```
[TITLE|prefix=anything|suffix=a] [STORENAME|prefix=another thing] [DYNAMIC|limit=10|seperator=-|random=1|reverse=1|prefix=one more thing]
```

What is the reason that those attributes are missing?

### Update

If I am not mistaking, my main problem is the if-statement:

```
if (mtPr.query[mtPr.settings.activeLang].includes(replace)) {
```

With this if-statement, I would like to check if either *TITLE* has the attribute *prefix* or *STORENAME* has the attribute *prefix* or *DYNAMIC* has the attribute *prefix*. But this is a bad workaround since the value of `replace` is always `prefix` (see line numbers 241, 245 and 251). And since we already have `prefix` in the WHOLE string, it means that we're caught in that if-statement every single time. So a possible solution could be, checking if the parameter `replace` is included AND does it belong to the parameter `search`.

Comment: If I add `console.log(regex);`on line 215 in the javascript file, I see multiple patterns being logged. If the pattern works here, are you sure that you are not accidentally doing multiple replacements?

Comment: @Thefourthbird I am not sure. Try to comment out line #241. You will see that it works now for the second attribute but no longer for the other ones.

Comment: Did you try to set the `global` flag for the regex to ensure that the replace gets applied to all matches. An example would be: `new RegExp('the regex', 'g');`

Comment: @mottek, yes I have tried that already but that didn't work. I have just updated my question. Not sure, but I think that I found the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have described in my question, the problem was really the if-statement. This how I could resolve it:

```js
  const searchMatchesReplace = new RegExp(`(?<=${search}.+${replace}=)[^\\]|]+`);
  if (searchMatchesReplace.test(mtPr.query[mtPr.settings.activeLang])) {
    const regex = new RegExp(`(?<=\\[${search}\\|[^\\]]*${replace}=)[^|\\]]+`, 'g');
    result = mtPr.query[mtPr.settings.activeLang].replace(regex, value);
  }
  // Replace parameters if they do not exist
  else {
    const regex = new RegExp(`(\\[${search}(?:\\|[^\\][]*)?)]`, 'gi');
    result = mtPr.query[mtPr.settings.activeLang].replace(regex, `$1|${replace}=${value}]`);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
function replace(search, replace) {
  const regex = new RegExp(`(${search}[^\\[\\]]*\\|prefix\\=)[^\\|\\[\\]]+`); 
  obj.prefix = obj.prefix.replace(regex, '$1hello');
}
```

Comment: I tried that but not working as expected. This is the result: `[TITLE|prefix=hello|suffix=a] [STORENAME] [DYNAMIC|limit=10|seperator=-|random=1|reverse=1]`